# Lib for Android and MIDP?

Tags: java, android, midp

Is it possible to share a Java library (in the form of a jar file) between Android and MIDP projects? If that is the case, which Java version should I compile with? The library does not use any Android or MIDP specific stuff.

Answer (score 2):

No it's impossible, since Android and J2ME use different VM. Android's one called Dalvik VM and J2ME's KVM - so they're generating different bytecodes.

Comment: You can add a normal JAR file to an Android project and have it converted to the correct format at build time.

Comment: As long as the library doesn't use any classes that are not part of Android, you can pass it to the dx tool that generates the .dex file from which the .apk is built.